# Load parameters to String.format from String in Java

Tags: java, string.format

I have this line of code:

```
String.format(query, dateFrom, dateTo);
```

dateFrom and dateTo are variables holding a string each

I would like to read the arguments which I pass to the String.format (apart from the query variable) from a string.

For example,

I'd like to have

```
String input = "startDate, amount, value";
```

and I can input this in the String.format call which can be equivalent to:

```
String.format(query, startDate, amount, value);
```

I have no idea if something like this is possible and would appreciate some feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to separate your input String by commas?

Comment: The string can be in any format
what I need is to be able to read a string, convert to the relevant variables and feed it to the String.format

Comment: It looks like you may want to use Map with <nameOfVariable,Value> rather then simple variables if you want to have dynamic access to `value` via `nameOfVariable`.

Comment: "The string can be in any format" : i guess there is a problem, if there is no known format, how do you want to be able to parse something without knowing its structure ?

Comment: What do you have inside your `input` variable? The actual value to be passed to `String.format()` or just variable names defined somewhere?